# How to calculate volatilities

Tags: r

I am following this example I want to share: But still I cant find the volatilities. I have time series daily data with no dates only observations 2425. Years 10. Average days 252.

```
# Example of usage of BigVAR package on the volatilities data that are included
library(BigVAR)
 ## Loading required package: lattice
data(volatilities)
big_var_est <- function(data) {
    Model1 = constructModel(as.matrix(data), p = 4, struct = "Basic", gran = c(50, 50), VARX = list(), verbose = F)
    Model1Results = cv.BigVAR(Model1)}
# Perform the estimation
oo <- big_var_est(log(volatilities[apply(volatilities>0, 1, all),]))
```

[image]